# Python, код почему то не хочет запускаться, не понимаю в чём ошибка

Tags: python, vosk

Я не понимаю почему он не работает просит ввести модель , но я ввожу и он говорит что её нет , хоть я и указываю папка в которой она находиться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: КОД]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Папка 'model не содержит файлов модели. Убедитесь, что вы правильно указали путь к модели в конструкторе Model. Если вы не уверены в относительном пути, используйте указание абсолютного пути. -- Дословный первод

Comment: Причина:
Ошибка возникает из-за того, что библиотека Vosk не смогла найти файлы модели распознавания речи, которые вы указали.

Возможные причины:
Неверный путь к модели: Самая вероятная причина - это опечатка в пути, который вы указали в конструкторе Model (у вас с маленькой, а в коде указан с большой). 
Отсутствующие файлы модели: Также возможно, что файлы модели повреждены или отсутствуют. Модели Vosk обычно распространяются в виде архивов, которые нужно распаковать.

Comment: я не понял о чём вы , можете немного понятней ?

Comment: У вас ошибка в 6 строке, попробуйте указать название вашей папки в коде с маленькой буквы (не Model а model)